# How to get all images uploaded by an app using facebook graph?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a facebook photo contest app. Users can upload an image via the app and it goes on their wall and into an album automatically created for my app. However I cannot find any way using the graph api to get the array of uploaded images for all users. Is this possible? I thought...

```
    $facebook->api("/$app_id/photos?access_token=$app_long_life_access_token");
```

would work but it returns an empty array.

The photos are uploaded using...

```
    $facebook->api($this->app_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
```

I can access a single image using its id and the app's token but this will require looping through every single image id to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a users photo album (even if it was created by your application), you'll need a valid user access token. It's *their* album after all. If a user changes their password or even uninstalls your application, you will no longer have access to their content.

To keep track of all these photo's you'll have to monitor each upload and store it (in your database for example).

Facebook doesn't usually allow you to collect masses of data in this way. You will have to query each individual user or photo to get this info if you don't store it in some other method.